# Как программно выделить колонку в чужом SysListView32?

Tags: winapi, delphi

Здравствуйте :)

Есть чужое приложение, в нём список SysListView32 с девятью элементами. Как программно выбрать один из них? Понимаю, что скорее всего SendMessage, но как через него правильно?
С уважением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может что-нибудь вроде

```
SendMessage(xHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0);
SendMessage(xHandle, WM_KEYUP, VK_TAB, 0);
```

За правильность не ручаюсь - первое что пришло в голову.

Comment: Спасибо, но это не то, это послать клавишу. А нужно конкретный элемент выделить)

Comment: Посылай клавишу до тех пор пока не выделится нужный элемент )

Comment: В моём случае это неприменимо, клавиша TAB  там не работает

Answer (score 2):

1. Определить дескриптор окна/эелемента (в вашем случаи список). Вот функции: [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx) (первый параметр имя класса (SysListView32 ?), второй - заголовок окна, в вашем случаи это текст выбранного значения; любой параметр можно оставлять null), [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500(v=VS.85).aspx), и [список](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632595%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) функций.
2. послать сообщение функцией [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(v=VS.85).aspx). Про сообщения посмотрите [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#system_defined), в вашем случаи, думаю, нужны [List View Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485961%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Если не получается, поэкспериментируйте с разными типами элементов управления, разными сообщениями. Можете воспользоваться утилитами, при помощи которых можно отловить поступающие в окно сообщения (запускаете программу, производите событие, которое вам нужно делать программно, и смотрите, какие события при этом поступили в то или иное окно)

Comment: утилита spy++, я понимаю, смотрел, там очень много сообщений просто, не пойму, какое нужно. Как хэндл элемента узнать - второстепенное, с этой задачей я думаю, справлюсь легко.
А вот с какими параметрами SendMessage - в этом проблема :)

Comment: Да, spy++ из состава VC++ подойдет. Сообщения можно фильтровать, например MouseMove'ы не нужны.  
Если известен индекс нового значения, отправляем [LVM_SETSELECTEDCOLUMN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761202%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), что должны содержать wParam и lParam в документации написано.

Comment: хэндл элемента определил правильно, LVM_SETSELECTEDCOLUMN ничего не дало :(
Посылал так:

h1:=FindWindow('чужое окно', nil);
h2:=FindWindowEx(h1, 0, 'SysListView32', nil);
SendMessage(h2, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, 10);

Comment: Сначала нужно узнать, какие группы сообщений принимает ваш элемент SysListView32. Вроде spy++ показывает имена поступающих сообщений, по ним это можно определить. "List View Messages" я написал как возможный вариант, не факт, что они подходят.  

[LVM_INSERTITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761107%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - добавление нового элемента, lParam должен *указывать* на структуру [LVITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774760%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), где хранится добавляемый элемент.  
Нужно понимать, что такое указатели, как с ними работать.